# How can I add a SharePoint group as a term group manager in managed metadata?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, groups, term-store

I have been requested to replace the individual users indicated as group manager for a particular term group with a SharePoint group. The group name checks out fine, but when I attempt to save it returns the following error:

[image: Term store unavailable warning]

Everything seems fine. The term store is definitely available; we're using the group for column data and search refiners and they're working 100%. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the **Group Managers** description states "Enter user names, group names, or e-mail addresses in order to grant group manager permissions", you **cannot** use a *SharePoint* group. From [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6cf88cd-a7e5-4543-aece-2c40631fdfbb/the-operation-cannot-be-complete-the-term-store-may-be-unavailable-in-term-store-management-tool?forum=sharepointadmin):

> SharePoint Group[s are] defined at [the] Site Collection Level while [the] Term Store is defined at [the] Farm Level.
>
> Active Directory groups can be used, but SharePoint Groups are not available at this time.  This is because Managed Metadata is a global term store and SharePoint groups are managed only within a single Site Collection.

#### References

- [TechNet: The operation cannot be complete. The term store may be unavailable" in term store management tool](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6cf88cd-a7e5-4543-aece-2c40631fdfbb/the-operation-cannot-be-complete-the-term-store-may-be-unavailable-in-term-store-management-tool?forum=sharepointadmin)